# Can't define __BOOTLOADER for linker script of PIC24FJ128GC006

Tags: bootloader, microchip, linker-scripts, pic24

I am making a USB Bootloader for PIC24FJ128GC006 and I am going to map part of the flash memory for the Bootloader and the Application code.
I added the linker script from Microchip MLA v2015_08 usb device bootloader to my PIC24FJ code file.
In the linker file, the `__BOOTLOADER` must be defined in order to access the `0x400` address region.

```
    #ifdef __BOOTLOADER   
       program (xr)   : ORIGIN = 0x400,         LENGTH = 0x35BE
    #else
       program (xr)   : ORIGIN = 0x4002,         LENGTH = 0x117F4
    #endif
```

In the main.c of my bootloader code, I have already `#define __BOOTLOADER`, but when I program the bootloader code to the PIC using ICD3 and check the program memory by using the PIC Memory Views of MPLAB Window Toolbar, the data is written to the `0x4002` address and not in the `0x400`.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I have solved my problem above. You should write #define __BOOTLOADER in the linker file, not in main.c. 
Another problem has risen though. In my code file dashboard, it indicates there that I have used 97% of the program memory after defining the __BOOTLOADER. So my question is that, can I remove some codes in the linker file to decrease the used program memory? If yes, how can I know what to remove in the vector tables?